# Batch: Comparing command line parameters

Tags: parameters, batch-file

I have a batch file which runs as follows:

```
c:\test.bt -abcd
```

Now inside the batch file, I have the following code:

```
if "%1" == "-abcd"
(
   do something
)
else
(
   do something else
)
```

but it keeps giving me the following error in execution:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
if "-abcd" == "-abcd"
```

Could someone please tell me whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe the parenthesis need to be on the same line...

From the `IF` documentation:

```
 IF EXIST filename. (
     del filename.
 ) ELSE (
     echo filename. missing.
 )
```

So, change it around to:

```
if "%1" == "-abcd" (
    :: Do something
) else (
    :: Do something
)
```

Also, you should probably change `%1` to `%~1` to remove any quotes beforehand.